# WebView Crashes when calling @JavascriptInterface method on Android 5.1.1

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, chromium

I'm having an issue with Android Webview specifically on Android 5.1.1 when I try to call a @JavascriptInterface method. This only happens under these conditions:

- Android 5.1.1
- Release Build

Because this is only happening on the release builds I tried removing Proguard completely but I'm still seeing the issue. What else could be happening on the release build that's causing this?  This is also not happening on any other version of Android 5.1.1.

Here's the crash:

```
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN 
APPLICATION: java_array == null
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     in call to GetArrayLength
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]     from void org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(long, long)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65] "JavaBridge" prio=7 tid=53 Runnable
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x13371190 self=0xaec3e000
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | sysTid=24904 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xaec59f00
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | state=R schedstat=( 2767866 2376821 16 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | stack=0x950fc000-0x950fe000 stackSize=1036KB
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #00 pc 00004e64  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (UnwindCurrent::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+23)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #01 pc 00003665  /system/lib/libbacktrace_libc++.so (Backtrace::Unwind(unsigned int, ucontext*)+8)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #02 pc 00256429  /system/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, char const*, art::mirror::ArtMethod*)+84)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #03 pc 00238fe7  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) const+158)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #04 pc 000b191b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+610)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #05 pc 000b2055  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+68)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #06 pc 001ccaa5  /system/lib/libart.so (art::JNI::GetArrayLength(_JNIEnv*, _jarray*)+612)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   native: #07 pc 015f868d  /data/app/com.google.android.webview-2/lib/arm/libwebviewchromium.so (???)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native method)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:39)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]   at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
F/art     (24750): art/runtime/check_jni.cc:65]
F/google-breakpad(24905): -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
F/google-breakpad(24905): V WebView:50.0.2661.86
F/google-breakpad(24905): O A arm 04 armv7l google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.1.1/LMY48B/1863243:user/release-keys
F/google-breakpad(24905): G OpenGL ES 3.0 V@104.0 AU@  (GIT@Id3510ff6dc)|Qualcomm|Adreno (TM) 330
F/google-breakpad(24905): S 0 951FD180 951FD000 00001000
F/google-breakpad(24905): S 951FD000
```

Comment: Did you find out why this exception is thrown? I'm having the same issue on my nexus 4 running 5.1.1

Comment: We had to stop using the interface on 5.1.1 devices as we could not find a workaround.